# Unicode problem with linux g++

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode

I have problem with unicode functions under my Ubuntu 10.10 linux. Lot of unicode functions doesn't work correctly. When I try following simple code:

```
#include <wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wprintf(L"test %s %s %s\n",L"one",L"two",L"three");
    return 0;
}
```

and compile using g++ (gcc version 4.4.5 Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4.-14ubuntu5) a have following results:

```
test o t t
```

instead of expected:

```
test one two three
```

Also other functions for working with unicode strings doesnt work correctly. Lot of my code I developing under MS Windows and this is my first linux programming atempts.

(Same bug appears on two linux machines where I tested this fragment)

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `%ls` instead, as given in the `wprintf(3)` man page.

Comment: Thank you, it helps. I spent tree hour searching what is wrong in my application ;-(. Under MS Visual studio %s works for ansi and unicode too.

Comment: `man` is your friend. But you may have to install a manpages-dev package or somesuch first.

Comment: Thank you. I already have installed manpages because this wasn't my first problem with porting my application to linux ;-).